# How do you remove an item from a JList while removing an Item from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, jlist

I have an `ArrayList` of `Objects` called `slist` filed with

```
Store sitem1 = new Store("Movie", 20.00, 500, 0, 0.00);
```

(More than just one `sitem` though. I have the `sitem` `toString` being printed to a JList

```
 for (int i = 0; i < customer.slist.size(); i++) {
        dlm.addElement(customer.slist.get(i).toString());//slist is an array of objects.
    }
    checkOutList.setModel(dlm);
```

When the user removes something from the `Jlist` I need the corresponding `slist` Item to be removed as well. I have no clue how to do it though.

Comment: Have you tried using a `ListSelectionListener`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081170/how-to-add-items-from-an-arraylist-of-objects-to-a-jlist. You got an answer to your question there and have not yet "accepted" the answer.

Comment: Don't have the data in two places. Instead you just add the `Store` object to the DefaultListModel. The default renderer of the JList will automatically invoke the toString() method when the object is rendered. So basically get rid of the ArrayList and just use the DefaultListModel to hold the data.

Answer (score 0):

get index of JList item by using `getSelectedIndex()` then using that index remove the item in ArrayList. Make sure if nothing is selected `getSelectedIndex()` will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the click event on the list, and then get the selected index from the event, and modify your list accordingly.

You also need to be careful because modifying your list will fire another event, and you need to make sure you're handling just the first one, so you need to remove the listener while you modify your model.

Here's a simple example that will give you the idea  Don't worry too much about the `initComponents()` method, that was generated by my IDE.  The key thing is to look at the event listener in the `main` method:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class TestJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public TestJFrame() {
    initComponents();
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
      layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
  }                      

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

        final DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        final List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("apple");
        items.add("pear");
        items.add("banana");

        for (String item : items) {
          dlm.addElement(item);
        }

        final JList checkOutList = new JList(dlm);
        checkOutList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        checkOutList
                .addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getFirstIndex() != -1 && !e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                      int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
                      checkOutList.removeListSelectionListener(this);
                      checkOutList.clearSelection();
                      dlm.remove(firstIndex);
                      items.remove(firstIndex);
                      checkOutList.addListSelectionListener(this);
                    }
                  }
                }
                );

        TestJFrame frame = new TestJFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setSize(200,200);
        panel.add(checkOutList);
        frame.add(panel);
        checkOutList.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```